# What is most secure CAPTCHA system?

Tags: captcha, bot

Artificial intelligence has now become a real security threat, some bots using advanced algorithms can solve even the most distorted of CAPTCHAS text at a high accuracy.

Assuming that I'm developing a form the some important banking operations which needs the implementation of the highest level of security , what is the **most** secure CAPTCHA system that I should use.
Actually I'm not seeking a specific product recommendation and I don't care about CAPTCHA's usability , just the most secure concept ( I wont complain if there are some implemented examples though)

Thanks :)

Comment: banking isn't really the kind of thing i would worry about robots using, given the other security in-place. CAPTHA is more to stop spam and automated sign-ups. I fear any sense of security you get from it is misplaced since hackers can usually read and type.

Answer (score 4):

Most secure is very subjective. Even Google's Captcha system has been known to be broken on ocassion, [one example](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/05/google-recaptcha-brought-to-its-knees/) out of many. Treat Captcha as a speed bump to deter people from putting in a lot of effort to break it. Checkboxes if your speed bump is good enough is... maintained by a trusted company, regularly updated, and is useable. I know you said ignore usability, but the human factor cannot be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I question your premise. A properly implemented site should be made secure without a Captcha. Once you have accomplished the appropriate level of security you need, adding a captcha should be thought of only as a convenience to prevent bots from submitting forms or taking certain actions. In other words, whether a bot performs the action, or a person does, should not make any difference regarding security. As an example, if you are worried about a bot attempting to brute force a user's login credentials, you should be blocking those attempts at the firewall level, and/or locking out the account for a certain amount of time after X number of attempts. This is why you rarely see Captchas on a login screen.

The value of using Captchas is when unauthenticated users can perform actions which write data somewhere, or when you offer a free tool that you don't want abused. Examples would be anonymous comment posting, signing up for a free account, sending an anonymous message, querying a free set of data, etc. The reason to use Captchas in those scenarios is to make it easier for the admins to wade through the "garbage" and prevent abuse of your systems, but in general the garbage or abuse in itself should not be causing security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Information security deals with Risk Analysis.

Part of this understanding is that no system is secure everywhere, all the time. The same applies to CAPTCHA systems.

CAPTCHA systems are designed to **deter (not stop)** automated scripts/bots. As you mentioned with AI, it is becoming a lot harder to find ways to challenge users to determine if they are bots or actual humans.

It has been argued to me the best way is to use a picture matching system, and customize this. For instance, if I was to have a site about the video game Half Life 2, I may wish to pick images that relate to it and see if a user can correctly pick all the pictures that include Alyx (a character from the game). This does two things:

- The attack must be designed specifically for the site (due to the unique images)
- A developer must address the way to reliably choose not only 1 image, but all of them.

The other area of concern is those human users who have disabilities such as vision impairments who can't differentiate similar colours, use screen readers, etc.

CAPTCHA systems must be constantly updated, as technology improves. To what degree you balance accessibility and security is an important factor. Some systems are much more secure than others, but prevent human users from accessing the systems.